# how to pass JSON return data to a URL route as parameter(laravel)

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, laravel, twitter-typeahead

Am working on a **Laravel** project and have successfully implemented a **search functionality** to search users from a database using **twitter typeahead** with jquery but am stuck. I want to pass the return JSON as a parameter to a route URL so that upon click of any given suggestion results am redirected to a user's profile page. Below is my code.

```
suggestion: function(data) {
                    return '<a href="{{route('profile', ['username'=> 
'+ data.username +'])}}" class="list-group-item"> ' + data.username + 
'</a>'
}
```

with this code am getting this result upon click
    http://battlefield.test/profile/+%20data.username%20+
instead, I want
    http://battlefield.test/profile/simon
or
    http://battlefield.test/profile/champion

Below is the route I want redirected to

```
// Profile
Route::get('profile/{username}', [
'uses'=>'UserController@profile',
'as'=>'profile',
'middleware' => ['auth'],
]);
```

Below is a link related to my research in case it will help
https://scotch.io/tutorials/implementing-smart-search-with-laravel-and-typeahead-js

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use urldecode() to decode for this problem. like this <?php  echo urldecode('We%27re%20proud%20to%20introduce%20the%20Amazing'); ?> I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Am lost. kindly elaborate @SoulCoder how can implement that in laravel

Comment: Can we see the returning json ? Also are you handle with json data inside of a controller ?

Comment: `{id: 1, username: "forever", firstname: "Simplest", lastname: "symon", gender: "Male"}` here is my sample JSON which am assigning to data. am able to access **data.username** when not within the url but within the url its not working which is what i want@HasanTıngır

Comment: I see, I'm trying to escape from string

Comment: I couldn't make it :/ I always use without laravel methods in my js if you want to use it with that way.. `return '<a href="profile/"'+ data.username + 'class="list-group-item">'+data.username+'</a>'`

Comment: @HasanTıngır thanks for your suggestions, it worked for me. Look at how I implemented it on the answer below. thanks, again man.

Answer (score 0):

I finally came up with a solution. Normally to access a route with parameters from the view in Laravel, let's say you have the below route from the question above

```
// Profile
Route::get('profile/{username}', [
'uses'=>'UserController@profile',
'as'=>'profile',
'middleware' => ['auth'],
]);
```

Here are the two way to access it through a href:

option 1.

```
<a href="{{route('profile', ['username'=>here goes your parameter])}}"></a>
```

option 2.

```
<a href="/profile/{{here goes your parameter}}"></a>
```

And since in my case I was using JSON data to obtain the parameter which is not easily accessible inside the blade template "{{}}", the 1st option did not quite work for me (if anyone knows why could let me know) but the 2nd did. This how I went about it to pass the parameter to the URL from the JSON return data

```
'<a href="/posts/'+ data.username +'"></a>'
```

here is a sample return data which in this case am assigning to data

```
{id: 1, username: "syk", first_name: "symon", last_name: "kibaru"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried many tries to figure out how to pass an array into a route then accept it in the controller so there is the solution:

In the form action:

```
<form action="/purchase/{{ json_encode($items) }}" method="get">
```

In the route:

```
Route::get('/purchase/{items}', [
        'uses' => Controllers\PurchaseController::class,
        'as' => '/purchase',
    ]);
```

In the controller:

```
public function  __invoke($items)
    {
        json_decode($items);
    }
```